# Is there a length limitation of qDebug()<<?

Tags: qt, qdebug

In my code, I found one `qDebug()<<s;` didn't output the content given to it. It's very strange, so I output `s.length()`. It says 135254, so I'm wondering whether there is a limitation of length which is shorter than 135254? I have read the source header and do not find the result.

Comment: I am not sure about any size restriction I have printed larger json data using qDebug. 

Just my thought. I understand qDebug output  will get truncated when '\0' character is encountered. You could check if your variable s contains that character.

Comment: @Mugunth The s I output is QString, I thinks it has no problem.

Comment: Try it out. It'll be faster than waiting for an answer. And then you get to post your own answer and get sweet, sweet upvotes :)

Answer (score 1):

i noticed something similar...

This might narrow it down a bit (using Qt 5.5.1 with Windows mingw):

45000 character trace did not show up in qDebug.

10000 character trace did show up in qDebug.

I was able to qDebug my 45000 characters as 5 separate qDebug calls, each was something like this:

```
qDebug()<<foo.mid(20000, 10000);
```

then piece them together in a text editor.
it may have been a little nicer to use qDebug's noQuotes feature too, but i don't need to run my script again today so I'm not prettying it up right now.

Comment: The most strange thing is that it output all content (135254 length) after that day, I didn't change any words of my code.